# Possible Ethernet card fault

Tags: networking, debian, ethernet, debian-lenny

We have a server in a server room with 100mbit internet access.

Hardware:

- supermicro C2SBX

Software:

- Debian lenny

We use the integrated network card since 7 months. The past 1 month the server lost the internet connection repeadetly for 1-2min daily. Our internet provider changed the switch, but it didn't solve the problem. They told me that maybe the problem is the network adapter. What do you think is it the problem?

Can I somehow test it in debian?

Could you recommend a network card, which can solve the problem(we have 1pci, 1pciex8, 2pcx free slot)?

Update:

I got this image about the switch: http://i50.tinypic.com/2d7u8fc.png

They told me that it's maybe QOS, because the brodcast and multi out is high.

Comment: What's in the log files?

Comment: Which log file do you need? I don't know which can help.

Comment: dmesg, system log,...

Comment: poke through /var/log until you find something that looks related to the network driver or network status.

Comment: dmesg: http://pastebin.com/Fit5mMYb
What means the first two number before each line?

Comment: those are timestamps since the system last booted

Answer (score 3):

I'd just add a new card, and see if the problem persists. If it does, it's not the adapter.

Ethernet cards are cheap. You should be able to get a nice commodity gigabit card (pci) for less than 40 bucks.

Answer (score 1):

I'll weigh into this one having just experienced the same thing.

Replace your cable :)

Yes odd but the cable was replaced and the net speed is back to normal.

On cable replacement I found out that it wasn't wired properly which caused most if not all of the trouble. Some cable techs bypass the required cat5/6 specifications for wiring shorter cables and it can cause all sorts of intermittent problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have had rock solid results with Intel NICs. If you had to get a new one, I'd stick to the same and get a PCIe one.

It may be the 100Mb link that's causing you trouble.

Thinks to look at:

/var/log/kern.log (for warnings from your NIC driver)

output from 'ethtool eth0' -- this will show you what speed and settings the NIC is set at.

You can try turning off auto speed detection and hard coding the speed (100) and duplex (Full).

You could possibly have a cable problem. Swap out what's there with a new cable to test. (I hope you've already tried this).

I hope this helps.

Comment: kern.log contains: 
http://pastebin.com/BbZvGaj7

Comment: ethtool: http://pastebin.com/LYdqnDjd
I can't change the cables, because it's a server hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Once i had similar problems when the switch was able to sync with our speed and duplex setting.
In this case you should see some errors in ifconfig dev statistics.
As already said, give a look at the linux box logs and, if possible, the switches logs.
Last but not least, try to change the cables. A lot of times they give you problems without nothing anything on the machines.